# Python: Parsing multi line-records in a for loop with str.rstrip() using generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, generator, strip

I need to strip new line characters in a huge file `f` I am parsing two lines at a time. e.g. like this.

```
def foo(f):
  with open(f, "r") as f:
    for n, s in zip(f, f):
      #something with `n` and `s`
```

Is it possible to `str.rstrip` directly in the `for` loop line or do I need to do it separately within the `for` loop body. This does not work `for n, s in zip(f.rstrip(), f.rstrip()):`

(Question updated to make it more concise)

**UPDATE:**

These solutions from Barmar's answer and comments from  PaulCornelius below:

```
def foo2(f):
  with open(f, "r") as f:
    for n, s in zip ((line.rstrip() for line in f), (line.rstrip() for line in f)): 
      #Do something with `n` and `s`
```

and

```
def foo3(f):
  with open(f, "r") as f:
    g = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    for n, s in zip(g, g):
      #Do something with `n` and `s`
```

**UPDATE 2:**

If you want to parse several files one can make one generator per file (here two files):

```
def foo4(f1, f2):
  with open(f1, "r") as f1, open(f2, "r") as f2:
    g1, g2 = (line.rstrip() for line in f1), (line.rstrip() for line in f2)
    for n1, s1, n2, s2 in zip(g1, g1, g2, g2):
      #Do something with `n1`, `s2, `n2` and `s2`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions.

```
for n1, n2 in zip([line.rstrip() for line in f1], [line.rstrip() for line in f1]):
```

But this doesn't process the file two lines at a time. Each list comprehension processes the whole file, so `n1` and `n2` will be copies of the same lines.

I think you can get what you want using a generator expression instead, since they're lazy:

```
for n1, n2 in zip ((line.rstrip() for line in f1), (line.rstrip() for line in f1)):
```

Comment: Ah - nice. Would that be more efficient than a line in the body?

Comment: Probably about the same.

Comment: Didn't OP intend to use two lines from `f1` instead of one from `f1` and another from `f2`?

Comment: @gyre Will `zip(f1, f1)` really do that?

Comment: Not from what I can tell, but I still don't think OP was planning to read from `f2`.

Comment: Yes `n, s in zip(f1, f1):` reads one line into n, the next into s. Then I can do something with those...

Comment: @user3375672 Try the generator version, see if it works correctly.

Comment: can I use it like map(rstrip, f1) when its a method  ( my ide says "Undefined name 'rstrip'" )

Comment: In the generator approach, I think you have made 2 generators and you want to have only one, like this: `g = (line.rstrip() for line in f1); for n1, n2 in zip(g, g)`

Comment: @Barmar: the generator expression wotked like a charm - I will try if the one suggested  does the same.

Comment: @PaulCornelius That will probably work, too. I was thinking that since the generators are lazy, you can have two that read from the same file, and they'll each pull a line out when they're called in sequence.

Comment: @PaulCornelius: your solution works as well - it seems more consise than Barmar's.

Comment: @PaulCornelius: How would you add lines from say two files into the same generator `g` ?  This works not it seems : `g = ((line.rstrip() for line in f), (line.rstrip() for line in f2)); for n1, n2, s1, s2 in zip(g, g, g, g): ... `

Comment: How about (x for a in zip(f1, f2) for x in a)?  A combination zipper and  unzipper.